# Date and Time concatenation

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, concatenation, gs-vlookup

When I concatenate a `date` (DD/MM/YYYY) and a `time` (HH:MM:SS) in Google Spreadsheets and use it as a `Key` in `VLOOKUP` function - `VLOOKUP` cannot find it although the `Key` is there.

I've tried `=text(" "&C34,"DD/MM/YYYY")&" "&text(D34,"HH:MM:SS")` where `C34`=09/11/2015 and `D34` =12:00:00. The `Key`I am looking for is `09/11/2015 12:00:00`.

Why isn't `VLOOKUP`seeing the key?

Answer (score 0):

I think for date in A1 and time in B1 is should be:

```
=A1+B1
```

With that in C1 and a column (E) of date/times and (F) of associated values, a lookup like this should work:

```
=vlookup(C1,E:F,2,0)
```